# set cursor focus on other edittext in android after done on keyboard button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have following view in xml file

`-Linearlayout
-Edittext (edone)
-Edittext (edtwo)`

Below code in Java file

```
edtwo.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {

                    edtwo.setText("");
                    edone.setText("");
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                    edtwo.requestFocus();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

After click on Done button in keyboard,cursor want to move in `edone` edittext field but remaining cursor focus on `edtwo`. how to change cusor focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
  edtwo.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            edtwo.setText("");
            edone.setText("");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

            edone.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: try that also but after complete logic bydefult cursor focus to edtwo

Comment: you want to when a second editext perform done the action then both editetxt clear, keyboard hide and automatically set focus first editext right?

Comment: @Neil then above code working well I have checked it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162863/discussion-between-mahesh-vayak-and-neil).

Answer (score 0):

just call this and it will reset the focus again to edone after done or keyboard is hide.

```
 edtwo.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // do your stuff here
             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
             edone.requestFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this-:

```
YourEditext.requestFocus();
```

Comment: try that after complete method call in side if codition automatically set focus to edtwo